# Mongo Shell Querying one collection with the results of another

Tags: mongodb, shell, mongodb-query

I have 2 different collections and I am trying to query the first collection and take the output of that as an input to the second collection.

```
var mycursor = db.item.find({"itemId":NumberLong(123)},{"_id":0})
var outp = "";
while(mycursor.hasNext()){    
    var rec = mycursor.next()
    outp = outp + rec.eventId;
}
```

This query works fine and returns me a list of eventIds.

I have another collection named users, which has eventId field in it. A eventId can repeat in multiple users. So for each eventId I get in the above query I want to get the list of users too.

My query for the second collection would be something like this :

```
db.users.find({"eventId":ObjectdId("each eventId from above query")},{"_id":0})
```

My final result would be a unique list of users.

Answer (score 1):

Whell this should basically work ( to a point that is ):

```
db.events.find({ 
    "eventId": { "$in": db.item.find({ 
        "itemId":NumberLong(123)
    }).map(function(doc) { return doc.eventId }) }
})
```

Or even a bit better:

```
db.events.find({ 
    "eventId": { "$in": db.item.distinct("eventId",{ 
        "itemId":NumberLong(123) }) }
})
```

The reason is that "inner query" is evaluated before the outer query is sent. So you get an array of arguments for use with [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/).

That is basically the same as doing the following, which translates better outside of the shell:

```
var events = db.item.distinct("eventId",{ "itemId":NumberLong(123) });

db.events.find({ "eventId": { "$in": events } })
```

If the results are "too large" however, then your best approach is to loop the initial results as you have done already and build up an array of arguments. Once at a certain size then do the same `$in` query several times in "pages" to get the results.

But looking for "ditinct" eventId via [`.distinct()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) or [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) will help.